# I am getting garbled text when debugging asp.net webform from Visual Studio 2013 in my browsers

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

When I go to start debugging a webform I have created in Visual Studio 2013 using any browser, the page comes up garbled.  However when I publish it to a web server, it is fine.

I already searched the web and tried to disable the browser link as others have suggested.  I tried recreating the code in a new webform.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled IISExpress and Visual Studio 2013. Please see the image attached as to what it is doing.  Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Error when debugging]

Comment: Looks like the web server hosting your app within Visual Studio, when running in Visual Studio, is compressing the web page incorrectly.

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: Not familiar with VS, but check the properties/setting in VS for the built-in web server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mark,

it was definitely the compression setting.  I searched online for it and changed it in the applicationhost.config file and that fixed it.